# How to get the origin URL from a "doPost" request on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I've been trying to identify the origin of a POST request made to a Google Apps Script `doPost()` content service;

```
function doPost(request) {
   // Something like this:
   var originURL = request.headers.URL; // http://myurl.com

}
```

Since I have published it ("Deploy as web app"), to 'Anyone, even anonymous',
it has the following header:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

So I want to control it's access in my code.

Is it possible?

Comment: i too am looking for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can not use direct post method in other aplication but you can use URL parameters passing try following.
Publishing script makes sure you have updated version and copy /exec link.
you can pass URL parameters like https://script../../exec?=para1=1012D.

More details [Click Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)